# table:tr:(click) => Triggers *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table within this data from an API, I allow the tablerows to be clicked so the data can be changed with background code:

```
<tr [ngClass]="tablerowClass" *ngFor="let dataObject of data$ | async" (click)="!allowClick || changeTable(dataObject.id)">
    <td *ngFor="let key of createTableArray(dataObject)" class="{{ getTableColumnClass(key.key) }}">
        <div [innerHTML]="key.value"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the rows should NOT be click-able I added the 'allowClick', yet when they click the row, the function 'changeTable()' is not called, but the page is refreshing because the '*ngFor' loop is triggered again...

Which is really annoying because when you click and drag to copy, it refreshes the page and your selection will be gone...

Can anyone explain why and how to disable this?

If you need any other information, simply ask me :)

Comment: why not use `allowClick` inside the `changeTable` function and just skip the code if `allowClick` is `false`

Comment: @Thatkookooguy that won't solve my problem, if I put the allowClick everywhere, even in the createTableArray function, it will clear the whole table, since it gives back no data anymore, I simply don't want my table to be refreshed when I click the row

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't understand what you meant by that ._. D:

Comment: @runefist not sure why. maybe you should also include a snippet of your typescript or more of your html. sounds to me like the problem you mention that will happen by moving `allowClick` anywhere hints on a bigger problem then this snippet

Comment: Have you tried trackBy?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this
(click)="!allowClick || changeTable(dataObject.id)"
Try this
(click)="allowClick ? changeTable(dataObject.id) : ' ' "

Or

Call that function changeTable and check your condition allowclick inside that function block to execute rest of the code.